# Self Join in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have been trying to fetch records from same table depending on parent_id concept of child and parent. One extra column is sequence that defines sorting order.

My data is...

```
Sr.No | Name         | parent_id       | Sequence
1.    | Customer     | 0               | 0
2.    | orders       | 0               | 5
3.    | General      | 0               | 10
4.    | All          | 1               | 0
5.    | Purchased    | 1               | 5
6.    | Non-Purch    | 1               | 10
7.    | Pending      | 2               | 0
8.    | Change Pass  | 3               | 0
9.    | Logout       | 3               | 5
```

I want to fetch out data in **single execution**. Though I am not able to use outer join as it is not supported by mysql.

My Tried sql is..

```
SELECT b.* FROM soi_admin_menu a RIGHT JOIN soi_admin_menu b ON a.menu_id = b.parent_id WHERE 1=1 AND a.parent_id = 0 ORDER BY a.sequence, b.parent_id ASC
```

I want data like this in sequenced manner.

```
  --Customer
  --All
  --Purchased
  --Non-Purchased
  --Orders
  --Pending
  --General
  --Change Password
  --Logout
```

with all fields. My DB is MySQL

Comment: outer join not supported? [I don't think that's correct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html), also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) for more info on how to emulate full outer joins.

Comment: Exactly thats true. The user to question that you have mentioned have solved using Keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you want? Your list of rows seems quite arbitrary to me; in terms of sequence-ID and parent-ID, you've posted (0,0), (1,0), (1,5), (1,10), (0,5), (2,0), (0,10), (3,0), (3,5). I don't see logic.

Comment: Simply I ahve fruits (Apple, Mango, Pineappli), Vegetables (Potato, Onion), Fatfood(Pizza, Burger)etc I have this form of data I want to divide data in same format as written above according to sequence it have. Means First record to be Fruits then Apple, Mango, Pineapple, then 5 record as Vegetables 6 record is POtato thn, Oninon..

I hope you are now clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it without OUTER JOINS, UNIONS or additional assumptions.

If you could assume, that Sequence and Sr.No give the same order for rows with parent_id = 0, you could try something like:

```
SELECT soi_admin_menu.*, 
    CASE 
        WHEN parent_id=0 THEN Sr.No * 10000 
        ELSE parent_id * 10000 + 1 + Sequence
    END as my_order 
FROM soi_admin_menu 
ORDER BY my_order;
```

Note that this solution gives you a limit on Sequence, id and parent (10000 in this case). To get rid of the limit, use string concatenation and sort by a string temporal column with a lower-than-any-character hash in case of the root rows.

With no OUTER JOINS, UNIONS or additional assumptions there is just no way to say which of

```
6.    | Non-Purch    | 1               | 10
7.    | Pending      | 2               | 0
```

goes first.

Comment: Can you write complete query. I haven't used the case before.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
   CASE
       WHEN parent_id=0 THEN Sr.No * 100
       ELSE parent_id * 100 + Sequence
   END as my_order
FROM soi_admin_menu a
```

Comment: Kudos but I select @bartosz Question correct as he replied first. Up to you also.. Thanks